# Fetch is done after statements in .then

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component which is fetching data from server, and then passing result to another component.

```
getData(args) {
    return fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/offers?title=${args}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((services) => { this.setState({ services }); });
}
```

In child component I want to pass url in callback function and then do something with result (in this case console.log services), but console.log is firing before fetching data is over.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.validPhrase === false) return;
    this.props.updateSearchPhrase(this.state.searchPhrase);
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state.searchPhrase)
        .then(console.log(this.props.services));
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`then(console.log(this.props.services));`

You're immediately calling the console here. You need to enclose it in a function:

`then(() => console.log(this.props.services));`